# How can I query for all pull requests that originated from a github organization?

Tags: github, github-api

How can I query for all pull requests that originated from a github organization? I.e. projects that have been forked into the organization and started a pull request back to the original project (outside of the organization).

I could probably query for all repositories in that organization and check the pull requests, but that would not work anymore if the repository has been deleted from the organization after the merge.

The goal is to get a list of contributions from my organization to other projects.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use the GitHub Search Issues API (V3) and search for all issues that contains each of your commits. This is rather laborious since you might have many commits and you will miss all contributions that have ended in private repositories. But this is the best response I could think off. ref. [Search issues based on commit sha](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues-and-pull-requests/#search-by-the-commit-shas-within-a-pull-request)